# Configurar un script linux para que corra con los permisos de otro usuario

Tags: linux, shell, seguridad

### Mi necesidad en concreto es la sigiuente:

Un script del `usuario1` tiene que poder ejecutarse por cualquier usuario del grupo1 (eso lo sé hacer), pero cuando se ejecute tiene que tener los permisos del usuario1.

Sería algo equivalente al concepto de [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) de crear una función con `security definer`.

*Quizás sea necesaria la intervención de un `sudoer` para esa configuración, eso me parece razonable. (Sé que puede haber algún error en los comandos, eso lo arreglo después, la pregunta es solo sobre delegar permisos)*

### Posibles casos de uso:

#### 1) acceso controlado a recursos:

```
cat recibir_mensaje.sh
echo "$DATE - $1" >> /home/usuario1/mensajes-recibidos.log
```

Podría de ese modo el `usuario1` permitir agregar mensajes en el archivo `mensajes-recibidos.log` de una manera controlada sin necesidad de permitir la escritura en el archivo si se lograra que el script `recibir_mensaje` corriera con permisos de `usuario1` aunque lo ejecute `usuario2`

#### 2) delegación controlada de tareas administrativas:

Imaginemos el usuario `subadmin2` al que queremos permitirle crear usuarios que pertenezcan al grupo `gr_comun`. Nada más que eso. Podríamos tener un script:

```
cat crear_usuario_comun.sh
adduser $1
adduser $1 gr_comun
```

que ese script corra con permisos de root pero no darle a `subadmin` permiso de sudo sino solamente permiso de ejecutar `crear_usuario_comun.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontré la manera de permitir a un usuario que no es root (ni está en los grupos de admin) ejecutar un script que corra como root para hacer ciertas tareas administrativas delegadas (como las del ejemplo de la pregunta)

## la solución

> Dar permisos limitados a través de /etc/sudoers para ejecutar solamente ese script como root

### el ejemplo

Imaginemos el usuario `subadmin` que queremos que tenga permiso de ejecutar `/opt/crear_usuario_comun.sh`

Con un usuario administrador configuramos el script para que tenga:

```
sudo cat /opt/crear_usuario_comun.sh
adduser $1
adduser $1 gr_comun
```

Y agregamos una linea en `/etc/sudoers` utilizando el comando `visudo`

```
sudo visudo
```

agregamos al final del archivo...

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
#...
subadmin ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /opt/crear_usuario_comun.sh
```

luego el usuario `subadmin` ya puede realizar su tarea delegada para crear el usuario común (o sea dentro del grupo común):

```
sudo /opt/crear_usuario_comun.sh usuario1
```

Answer (score 1):

La opción más razonable es configurar adecuadamente `sudo`.

Quieres saber si es posible ejecutar un `script` con el bit `suid` activado...

Respuesta corta,

No, la política de seguridad del `kernel` provoca que los `scripts` no se puedan ejecutar con el bit `suid` activado.

Respuesta larga,

Sí, esta misma política permite que un archivo binario ejecutable con el bit `suid` activado, ejecute un `script` arbitrario. Si creas un programa con los derechos necesarios y éste programa ejecuta tu `script`, éste último lo hará bajo los derechos del ejecutable.

De todas formas; lo más recomendable, desde el punto de vista de la seguridad, es configurar `sudo` para que los usuarios puedan ejecutar el `script`.

Comment: No me había dado cuenta que en tu frase "De todas formas; lo más recomendable, desde el punto de vista de la seguridad, es configurar sudo para que los usuarios puedan ejecutar el script." estaba la pista para encontrar la solución que necesitaba.